# Can I use Visual Source Safe and Team Foundation at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

Our company has a number of projects on Visual Source Safe and I was wondering if it would be possible to migrate gradually as opposed to having to move all of the projects on to Team Foundation.

To explain the situation further, we have Visual Studio set up so that it automatically checks out files from VSS whenever they are modified by a user. If I change one of the projects over to Team Foundation, will I be able to keep this functionality whilst using Team Foundation?

Comment: You will be able to keep the functionality insofar as Team Foundation Server has the same functionality.  However, once the code is migrated you need to stop using VSS for that project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The import tool for VSS to TFS will import your entire VSS repo into TFS. Once in you are on TFS and have to move forward.

I would recommend that you move to TFS very quickly as support for VSS ended quite some time ago.